# Flash-like visual effects in JS / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dhtml

I know there are thousand of visual effects made in JS that can be found on Google. But most of that effects are useless in web-design, or are outdated like "clock following mouse cursor" :| Also I know sites like http://www.chromeexperiments.com and http://www.dhteumeuleu.com but those examples make web-browser uses 100% CPU power and mostly looks good only as an example.

What I'm looking for is effects that looks nearly impossible to achieve without Flash, that not use 100% CPU, and doesn't disturb user. **I need it for game web-page.** One of very good examples is this one: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/trovster.html - look carefully at header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jParallax](http://webdev.stephband.info/parallax.html) is an efficient jQuery plugin that does game-like parallax scrolling. Useful for web design? Well... if you *really* want something that acts like a video game, maybe.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at **[jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/)** - which provides abstractions for low-level interaction and animation, advanced effects and high-level, themeable widgets, built on top of the [jQuery JavaScript Library](http://jquery.com), that you can use to build highly interactive web applications.

Here is a list of websites using [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/):

- [Arcadya](http://www.arcadya.net/) – Torrents & subtitles for TV series (iGoogle/Netvibes style)
- [Beltrami](http://www.beltrami.be/) – Product selector, picture albums, searchfunctions, …
- [EA](http://www.ea.com/) – Video Games
- [iRich](http://www.irich.tw/) – Keep tracking your expenses online. (Chinese 中文)
- [kolko.bg](http://kolko.bg/) – The only reliable Bulgarian Internet shopping assistant.
- [MacWorld.fr](http://www.macworld.fr/)
- [PCworld.fr](http://www.pcworld.fr/)
- [Poker Square](http://plaes.org/games/poker_square/) – single-player card game
- [PartyHandbook](http://www.partyhandbook.co.uk/) – UK nightclub event listing guide

Demos and documentation: http://jqueryui.com/demos/